# Vue scoped styling not working with elements that have been added inside a slot

Tags: vue.js, sass

Moving my styling to a locale setup but seeing that when I insert element into slot containers they will not work. I guess this is normal if so is there a way to solve this, keep in mind NO I am not going to place the parent (.child) styling in the parent component and NO I want to keep my CSS in seperate scss files.

component (parent)

```
<template>
   <wrapper>
       <div class="child">Hello</div>
   </wrapper>
</template>
```

component (wrapper called)

```
<template>
   <div class="wrapper">
       <slot></slot>
   </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "../../../sass/components/_container.scss";
</style>
```

container.scss

```
.wrapper{
    background-color:#333;

    .child{
         background-color:#fff;// not doing anything
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `v-deep` selector, I believe this is what it is meant for. You use it like `.wrapper::v-deep .child { background-color:#fff; }`. See https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Comment: For what I know(cant test it right now) this will only work when the css code is inside the component and not in the scss file but I can be wrong

Comment: I dont think it should matter if it is in separate scss file. But let us know once you have tested.

Comment: Okay this works even in an scss file. I would say create answer and I will give you the points!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `v-deep` combinator to target child elements/components e.g.:

```
.wrapper::v-deep .child { background-color:#fff; }
```

See the [Deep Selectors documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) for more detail.

**Update**

It seems `::v-deep .child` has been deprecated. Use `::v-deep(.child) {}` or `:deep(.child) {}` instead. See the [RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0023-scoped-styles-changes.md) for more detail.

Comment: ::v-deep has been deprecated. I use .selector:deep{ .child{ //stuff} }

Comment: Do you have a link to the deprecated info? I haven't seen :deep yet.

Comment: I found the RFC on this change: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0023-scoped-styles-changes.md if anyone is interested.

Comment: To be honest I cant find the link anymore, it could also be the case that I was trying something and this worked.

Comment: FWIW, there is now a [`slotted:`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#slotted-selectors) selector, for just this situation. Usage (in this scenario) would be; `:slotted(.wrapper) { .child { // Your SCSS } }`.